Buttons on macOS do not look the same as iOS
The following button definition creates the correct style in iOS:
struct LoginButton: View {
  let viewModel: LoginViewModel

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: viewModel.logIn) {
      Text("Login.Button.Title")
        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold, design:.default))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
        .background(Color("SecondaryColor"))
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
  }
}


However, the button looks different in macOS. The button appears to have an 'inner button' with a white border, or there is a parent object that is larger than the purple part of the button. Note: both the white and purple parts are clickable:

Here is another view of the left side of the button in Xcode's preview window:

I would like to get rid of the white space so the button looks the same as it does in iOS, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A big part of the design of SwiftUI is that it automatically matches the standard look and feel of each platform. If you don't like it, you can try making it a catalyst or designed-for-ipad app instead of macOS native, or use shapes and touch handlers to make your own widgets.

I'd consider making a ButtonStyle that has the appearance you want

@Kevin I understand what you are saying, but that button looks very bad. I doubt it is what Apple intends buttons to look like. I tried every combination of style, overlay, etc. that I could think of, but nothing has worked so far. I am admittedly new, so I could be missing something that is obvious to an expert, but I am guessing it isn't supposed to be this difficult because it has been quite simple to get things 'right' for iOS.

As Kevin says (sort of), you're better off just using AppKit. SwiftUI is not very good on macOS. It certainly doesn't yet fulfill its implied promise of write once run anywhere, as you've discovered. So it's best to stop banging your head against this and go with what works.

@Anthony did you try defining a ButtonStyle? You should be able to make it look like whatever you want on macOS.

@jnpdx I thought I had tried to add a style, but I must have done it incorrectly. After following the instructions in the accepted answer, the style of the button matches what I see in iOS. I don't know what I did wrong when I first attempted to match the styles.

The accepted answer also doesn’t use a custom ButtonStyle - you may also want to explore implementing your own style.


... there is a parent object that is larger than the purple part of
the button.

In macOS, that parent object you mention is the button's border. To get rid of it, apply a .buttonStyle(.borderless) to the Button (not to the label of the button).
While at it, note that .cornerRadius is deprecated. You should use .clipShape:
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))

or clip the background in a shape:
.background(Color("SecondaryColor"), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))

The following code will give different results on iOS and macOS, as shown in the image:
import SwiftUI

struct LoginButton: View {
    // let viewModel: LoginViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            
            //Button with default style varies between iOS and macOS
            Text("Default style (macOS):")
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
            Button {
                //action here...
            } label: {
                Text("Log in")
                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold, design:.default))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 260, maxHeight: 60)
                    .background(Color(red: 0.39, green: 0.32, blue: 0.61))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            }
            
            //Button with borderless style is consistent between iOS and macOS
            Text("Borderless style (macOS):")
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
            Button {
                //action here...
            } label: {
                Text("Log in")
                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold, design:.default))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 260, maxHeight: 60)
                    .background(Color(red: 0.39, green: 0.32, blue: 0.61))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    LoginButton()
}


Note: Tested on XCode 16, macOS Sequoia, iOS 18 Simulator.

This reply is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain the details. I would have sworn I had tried .borderless, but I must have implemented the modifier incorrectly.
